# Multiple schedules in Azure Data Factory V1 Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there any way to create two triggers/Schedules in ADF pipeline, one with Month Start Date and another with Every Monday in ADF v1.

Comment: You could create two pipeline with the same set of activities and define different schedules for each of them as per your need.

Comment: That works but just to create a schedule, duplicating the pipeline code leads to code maintenance .. Is there any way to add 2 schedules in one pipeline?

Comment: This could be achieved in ADFV2 where one pipeline could be evoked via multiple triggers. I am not sure about ADFV1.

Answer (score -1):

I explained how to "trigger" a pipeline in Data Factory v1 here: [Azure Data Factory V1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49167400/azure-data-factory-v1/49195167#49195167)

If this works for you, you can create a runbook in Azure Automation and schedule it to run whenever you need. This way it is much more flexible, but may not work if you use WindowStart and WindowEnd a lot.

Hope this helped!